# How to distribute a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that I want to distribute across a client's company, what is the best way to do so? It is a private extension so I dont want to publish it on the chrome web store. What is the easiest way for me to give the IT department my extension and have them install it across their machines?